# How to get count 0 if data is not present in database using mySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm showing up monthly user registered on my app. For that, I have used the below query, which is working fine. But with this query, if no user registered in the month of June then no data is there against June. I want a row with month June and all other information set to 0. Can anyone please help me out with this?

`SELECT Month(createdon), count(*) as users,COUNT(if(roleid=1,1,NULL)) as instructor, COUNT(if(roleid=2,1,NULL)) as student FROM user_profile where Year(createdon) = Year(Now()) group by MONTH(createdon);`

I am getting the output as:

`Month(created on) | users | instructor | student |
        3        |   4   |      3     |    1    |
        4        |   7   |      5     |    2    |`

Here, Month 3 and 4 corresponds to March and April respectively.

But the actual output is:

`Month(created on) | users | instructor | student |
        1        |   0   |      0     |    0    |
        2        |   0   |      0     |    0    |
        3        |   4   |      3     |    1    |
        4        |   7   |      5     |    2    |
        5        |   0   |      0     |    0    |
        6        |   0   |      0     |    0    |`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT MONTH(createdon) AS month, COUNT(*) AS users, COUNT(IF(roleid=1,1,NULL)) AS instructor, COUNT(IF(roleid=2,1,NULL)) AS student
FROM user_profile
WHERE (YEAR(createdon) = YEAR(NOW()))
GROUP BY MONTH(createdon)
UNION
SELECT M.month, 0, 0, 0
FROM (SELECT 1 AS month UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) AS M
WHERE (M.month <= MONTH(NOW()))
  AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE (MONTH(createdon) = M.month)));
```

Comment: hey... This worked. Thanks...But I want to rearrange the output now. Will it be possible?

Comment: If you mean reordering, yes you can apply an ORDER BY clause to the end of the query (like ORDER BY month DESC), that applies to the complete result set.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience
So just use

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_profile WHERE MONTH(createdon)= 'yourmonth')
  ,SELECT 
     Month(createdon),
     COUNT(*) AS users,
     COUNT(if(roleid=1,1,NULL)) AS instructor, 
     COUNT(if(roleid=2,1,NULL)) AS student 
  FROM user_profile 
  WHERE Year(createdon) = Year(Now()) 
  Group BY MONTH(createdon)
,0)
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks but I am unable to run this query. I am getting `Error Code: 1064. 
      You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
      use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_profile  WHERE MONTH(createdon)= Month(NOW()))   S' at line 1 0.235 sec` as error

Comment: Hey, Any idea ?

Comment: If this didnt work either, tell me the version of your MYSQL Server so I can find another syntax

Comment: still getting error... I'm using MySQL workbench 8.0.11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195040/discussion-between-el-ham-and-ruchi-yadav).

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the sorted SQL result and iterate a custom range and insert either the given data or an empty result set.

```js
function getRange(from, to, result) {
    var i, j = 0;
    for (i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        if (result[j] && i === result[j][0]) {
            console.log(...result[j++]);       // slq result
        } else {
            console.log(i, 'empty row');       // row with zeroes
        }
    }
}

getRange(1, 6, [[3, 2, 5], [4, 3, 2]]);
```

Comment: I'm having an array of object, not a 2-D array

Comment: same way, just take the properties.

Comment: But I want an array which is having the values... not in the console

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing `row with 0 value` because data for given month is not there in your table and groupby will show data of months that are present.

You can generate a month list for given year -

```
select  TO_CHAR((current_date - interval '1 month' * a),'MM') AS mm FROM generate_series(1,12,1) AS s(a)
```

it will generate value like

```
01
02
03
.
.
```

Then you can write a subquery with this table and do `left join with your user_profile` table and you will get data as you have specified.

For more read, go through this [link](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/076DC33A3D38CE4BBC64D35DDD9DE70C0A2D9882%40mse4be2.mse4.exchange.ms).

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with a list of months.  This can be accomplished with a derived table:

```
SELECT m.mon, COUNT(up.createdon) as users,
       SUM(up.roleid = 1) as instructor,  
       SUM(up.roleid = 2) as student
FROM (SELECT 1 as mon UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as mon UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 as mon UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 as mon UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 as mon UNION ALL
      SELECT 6 as mon 
     ) m LEFT JOIN
     user_profile up
     ON m.mon = MONTH(up.createdon) AND
        YEAR(createdon) = YEAR(Now()) 
GROUP BY m.mon;
```

If you have a calendar table or numbers table, you can use that instead of the derived table.